# Show "no rows found" inside a JTable row if not found entry while filtering

Tags: swing

i have  a JTable with row filter.

once fitered if i didn't get any row then i have to show  a string  like "Nothing found to display " inside table as first row.

please do needful.

Thanks ,
Narasimha

Comment: @Narasimha: Please use a single login to Stockkoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/users/372404/narasimha-rao and http://stackoverflow.com/users/373085/narasimha

Answer (score 9):

I needed to solve this exact problem today and wasn't able to find a good answer online. In the end I came up with my own solution, which I think may be exactly what you want. I don't know if this is too late for your project, but perhaps it can help others:

`JTable.paintComponent(Graphics g)` will not be called unless the table has a height that is greater than 0. This causes a problem for empty tables, so we expand the `JTable` height if needed so that it will always be at least the size of the `JViewport` that is it's parent.

```
JTable tableName =  new JTable() {
  public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
    if(getParent() instanceof JViewport)
      return(((JViewport)getParent()).getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height);

    return super.getScrollableTracksViewportHeight();
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(getRowCount() == 0) {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g2d.drawString("Nothing found to display.",10,20);
    }
  }
}

containerName.add(new JScrollPane(tableName));
```

Comment: Nice although it doesn't take into account the height of table headers.

Comment: I think it looks more natural to show the container's color through the table when it is empty and displaying "no results". This can be achieved by adding `setBackground(getParent().getBackground());` within the `if` clause of `paintComponent()` and adding an `else` clause with `setBackground(Color.WHITE);`.

Answer (score 0):

If the filter has excluded all rows, the result returned by [`getViewRowCount()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#getViewRowCount%28%29) will be zero. You can update the GUI accordingly; `setToolTipText()` is handy if screen space is lacking.

Here's an example:

```
TableModel model = ...
JTable table = new JTable(model);
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
JLabel label = new JLabel("");
...
String s = "Rows: " + sorter.getViewRowCount()
pane.setToolTipText(s);
label.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a line of text in the multicolumn table can be quite difficult, the span AFAIK is not supported.
One possibility would be to hide all data columns (to show them later you have to memorize them somewhere) and show one column for the message.

An easier way would be to create a JPanel with CardLayout, add 2 cards - one containing table and one containing your empty data warning. If the filter returns empty result, show the card with empty warning, in other case - show the table.